# Unix Commands not working from Crontab

Tags: linux, terminal, cron, kill

I have this command in a bash script called run.sh

```
 kill $(lsof -t -i:34445)
```

On a terminal when i run this script using bash run.sh it works. However, i am using crontab to schedule this command. This comes up with the error that

```
 lsof: command not found
```

There was also another command that i tried fuser and that didnt work too. Can you tell me what is it that I am doing / not doing that makes this work in one case and not in another

this is my crontab setup

```
 PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
 PYTHONPATH="$HOME/development"

 58 * * * 1-5 bash /dir/run.sh > run.out 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Try `which lsof` to see where the binary is. On CentOS, it happens to be in `/usr/sbin/`. Same with `fuser`.

Comment: Aside: why are you putting the command in the background with the final `&`? It's already in the background as it's started by cron.